# Ctrl + F9 Does not update Formula Text on Excel 2009

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a lot of excel workbook that follows a template. Since each workbook has a lot of sheets. I usually just use the equal formula to refer to the heading of the first sheet for the succeeding sheets. (e.g. the title of the document, number of the document.)

The problem is I notice that when I insert a new formula, the cells format becomes a number again which does not evaluate the formula. Also even if I use Ctrl+F9, the formula does not work. Even If i change the format of the cells to General.

Sample Formulat is Sheet1!A2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I found CTRL + F9 does not recalculate the worksheet, it minimizes the workbook, so, maybe you're just pressing wrong keys?

> **F9**    Calculates all worksheets in all open workbooks.
>   **SHFT + F9** calculates the active worksheet in Microsoft Excel.
>   **CTRL + ALT + F9** calculates all worksheets in all open workbooks,
>   regardless of whether they have
>   changed since the last calculation.
>   **CTRL + ALT + SHFT F9** rechecks dependent formulas, and then
>   calculates all cells in all open
>   workbooks, including cells not marked
>   as needing to be calculated.
>   ***CTRL + F9*** minimizes a workbook window to an icon.

source [keyxl.com](http://www.keyxl.com/aaa33ef/136/Microsoft-Excel-Software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm)